# ASP.NET MVC LinkedIn Update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

Good day all.

Does anyone have any working example how to post LinkedIn Status Update using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: have you tried http://developer.linkedin.com/apis?

Comment: Well... I actually tried to do it myself, but I am always getting authorization error despite the fact that I have API and User keys and secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an excellent guide:

http://www.suddenelfilio.net/2010/08/24/linkedin-oauth-using-hammock-in-csharp-asp-net/